# What is the proper way of doing inference on a batch of images in Tensorflow for performance purposes

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

What I am trying to accomplish is doing inference in Tensorflow with a batch of images at a time instead of a single image. I am wondering what is the most appropriate way of handling processing of multiple images to speed up inference?

Doing inference on a single image is easily done and quite used in most tutorials, but what I have not seen yet is doing that in a batch-like style.

Here's what I am currently using at a high level:

```
pl = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
...
sess.run([boxes, confs], feed_dict={pl: image})
```

I would appreciate any input on this.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how your model is designed, you can just feed an array of images to `pl`. The first dimension of your outputs then corresponds to the index of your image in the batch.

Many tensor ops have an implementation for multiple examples in a batch. There are some exceptions though, for example [tf.image.decode_jpeg](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/decode_jpeg). In this case, you will have to rewrite your network, using [tf.map_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn), for example.